# How to update single row without having primary key

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table having column A and B . I'm planning to store only one row in this table.

My problem is how to update this table row using sqlite.

please if you can answer please mention...

Comment: Why don't you use `sharedpreferences` when your data is small?

Comment: @MohammedAtif hmm. thank you. Let Me try..

Comment: Using a database for a single row is an overkill. SharedPreferences should be your choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single row, you can just use a normal `UPDATE` statement. You don't need a `WHERE` clause, since you only have the single row.

However, it's not a good idea to have no primary key even if you don't need it at the moment. At some point you might think "Well, I really want another row" and this approach won't work anymore.

Comment: thank you kayaman, I won't need another row in future. becuase. my two columns are current usdRate and goldRate.  please see my update statment.

Comment: dbW.update(TABLE_RATES, cv, null); what should comes to null place.

Comment: What class is `dbW`?

Comment: it's SQLiteDatabase

Comment: Then according to [the javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), passing null as the where clause will update all rows, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET columnName = newValue
WHERE someColumn = someValue;
```

example table:

```
name age 
john 45
```

`UPDATE Table SET age = 23 WHERE name = 'john'`

But you should use id column as primary key.
Though if you only have one row you can exclude the `WHERE` clause:

`UPDATE Table SET age = 23`

Comment: thank you. you mean existing value as id for where clause ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one row you can update all table rows in one query.

Example: 
`UPDATE table_name SET A="new value A", B="new value B" WHERE 1`